# Is there any compatibility issue while using WiFi Direct between different cell phone vendors?

Tags: file-transfer, wifi-direct

I was trying to transfer a file via my LG Optimus L9 (T-mobile) WiFi Direct to my friend's Samsung Galaxy S3. It got connected successfully. However, shortly after sending initialization, I got an error "Sending Failed". Then I tried the other way i.e. receiving, but no success.

Later, I have tried with my other friend's Samsung Galaxy Note, but no success.

Nobody around me has an LG device with WiFi Direct feature.

Can someone tell me why is that going wrong?

Comment: Incompatible implementations between different manufacturers. I've read an article on that a while ago. To work around that, use a 3rd party app like e.g. SuperBeam.

Comment: Real odd and probably different, my LG blows out the wi_fi direct connection when the GPS kicked in (active not just switched).  I had been wondering why it was blowing out, when I spotted the location update occuring, the GPS symbol in the top bar at the same moment as the Direct disconnected again.  At first I thought it was the problem of the net Wi-Fi being connected at the same time, and had to "forget" that WiFi to reduce any conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using a 3rd party implementation just as Izzy suggested. My ROM doesn't have that feature so I typically use [Fast File Transfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.floriandraschbacher.fastfiletransfer&hl=en). It's a great app and only the host phone needs it. Currently it doesn't work with host HTC phones though.